# ActiveMQ Core bridge to cluster

Tags: activemq-artemis

Version : ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.1

I created a core bridge to a failover cluster.

broker A <--(core bridge)--> broker B[MASTER] <--(failover cluster)--> broker C[SLAVE]

When I created the bridge and the cluster, I don't used broadcast-groups and discovery-groups.
I used satic-connectors.

When I created the core bridge, I set IP and port of the broker B as the connector of the broker A.
I could failover successfully.

Although I didn't set IP and port of the broker C as the connector of the broker A, how could the broker A know IP and port of the broker C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client connects to a broker that has a slave the *broker* informs the client of the slave so that if it dies the client can try connecting to the slave. In your case, when the core bridge on broker A connects to broker B (which has broker C as a slave) then broker B informs the core bridge on broker A about broker C so that if broker B dies the core bridge on broker A will connect to broker C.